# Overflow property working strangely in Safari on both iOS and MacOS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have encountered a Safari specific problem with the css overflow property, while building a chatbot front-end using ReactJS. While on other browsers the messages overflow properly, in Safari they bunch up like so:
[Bunched up messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alxgB.png)

The CSS currently looks like this:

```
.Messages {
  height: calc(100% - 110px);
  min-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .Messages {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}
```

I've tried `overflow: auto` and `overflow: hidden` and various combinations of x/y axis manipulation but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for your comments and help!

Edit: Sorry no code for reproducing. I've solved, it was the use of `display: flex`. changed to `block` and it worked.

Comment: You should create a [mcve] that allows reproducing the problem. `.Message` is the container, and the stacking happens for the messages, so it is likely that the problem is in the combination of the css properties of the container and of the individual messages.

Comment: Not related to your problem. But if you use the eraser in an image processing program, it often only manipulates the alpha channel and does not delete the actual pixel information. So you shouldn't use that to "remove" critical information from an image because one can still retrieve that information due to that.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @t.niese ! Will bear in mind for next time 

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this is a flexbox with Safari issue. Using `display: block` instead of `display: flex` solves it.